# Lush meadows December time

Tags: hiking, camping, united-states

I am looking for a December time vacation destination in USA. A meadow type terrain. Somehow flat vast lush and green area and if possibly has wild flowers and rivers around that'd be ideal. Does anyone has a suggestion or recommendation of where should I look at?

**Do lush green meadows, preferably with blooming wild flowers and running water, exist in the US anywhere in December for a hiking or camping trip, and if so where?  We are willing to travel.**

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed as too broad.  The OP specified what she wanted quite clearly.  If she were asking about a summer vacation, it would have been too broad, because there are roughly 3 million square miles in the US where such a location could be found.  But in December?  That narrows it down sharply --  perhaps to nowhere?   The question really is there anywhere in the US where one can find lush green meadows, preferably with wild flowers, in December, if one is willing to travel.

Comment: I personally went with the flow as too broad, but I should have marked it as possibly off-topic. I feel it would be better suited in https://travel.stackexchange.com/ But then again, TGO is so broad that it could go either way.

Comment: Can't think of anywhere in the continental US. Southern CA desert has some wildflowers now but that isn't lush and green. Hawaii perhaps or some other tropical territory.

Comment: It was asked in Travel and closed as too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *may* have some luck in Florida.  The [Florida Wildflower Foundation](https://flawildflowers.org/whats-in-bloom/) list some things still in bloom.  I'd say poke around on their site; especially the links to South Florida parks.  It you're going to find anything in the continental US that's lush, green, and has wild flowers, that's the best bet I'd have.

That said, you might have more success if you are willing to split the requirements.  Find your meadows outside, but conservancies or botanical gardens might be the best places to view wildflowers, even in Florida.